# What is the everyday word to express "some food that tastes good if it is kept dry and bad if it absorbs moisture"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Some food like snacks should be kept in a dry environment without any moisture or humidity.

If these foods are left in the open humility air, they will become soft and taste bad.

**What is the everyday or common word to express that bad status?**

For example, "*I like to eat bread that has just come out of the oven. Bread will get **soggy / damp** if it is left in the open air.*"

Comment: I know of no single word that serves this purpose. Typical phrases are **keep dry / store dry / keep sealed / keep moisture out.**

Comment: I am looking for an adjective that expresses that state, an adj that says "wet to a level that causes bad taste"

Comment: Potato crisps and biscuits (both British Eng. terms) should be _crisp/crunchy_ and will _go soft_ or _lose their crispness_ if left out in the air. (In my experience, bread dries out and goes hard, but perhaps we are thinking of different types of bread!)

Comment: "everyday or common word" : stale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dry food that has become unpleasant or inedible due to improper storage (or because of its age) is described as ***stale***.

> **stale food such as bread is old and no longer fresh**
>
> a package of stale crackers
>
> **get/go stale:** Wrap the bread up well or it’ll get stale.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/stale

This is likely the closest answer to the question, however, it's not entirely fitting.  *Stale* either means *absorbed too much moisture* **or** *lost too much moisture*.

You need to know how much moisture the food is supposed to contain in order to tell what *stale* means.  For example:

If a potato chip has *gone stale*, it has absorbed enough moisture to change its texture and possibly its taste.

If a loaf of bread has *gone stale*, it has lost moisture, becoming dry and hard.

If a cookie has *gone stale*...we can't say.  Some cookies are meant to be crisp and dry and some soft and moist.  A *Chips Ahoy!* chocolate chip cookie is hard, so a stale *Chips Ahoy!* cookie has gotten moist.  A *Toll House* chocolate chip cookie is typically soft, so a stale *Toll House* chocolate chip cookie has dried out.

Answer (score 1):

“Dry” goods are sold and stored dry, usually in a sealed (or resealable) container, and will generally keep for weeks, months or even years as long as they’re kept dry. This does *not* include bread, but it does include many snacks and cooking ingredients.

“Fresh” goods, such as bread, produce and meat, are expected to only last a few days even if stored under ideal conditions, and it is understood they will go bad (stale, rotten, etc.) very quickly if not stored well.